# How can I connect my Power BI Service Dataset to Elasticsearch through Logstash? I need config file for this problem.?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I tried this config file but it is throwing an error.
it is my config file which i try:

```
input {
   http {
    http_method => "post"
    url => "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/your-dataset-id/"
    headers => {
      "Content-Type" => "application/json"
      "Authorization" => "Bearer access_tocken"
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
  index => "powerbi"
  }
}
```

Comment: What error is it throwing?